# How to mock window.Raven with Jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, sentry

I am unit-testing a custom piece of Sentry middleware for a Redux application. The testing framework of choice is Jest. I have tried every single which way to mock out `window.Raven` and cannot get it working.

```
window.Raven = {
   isSetup: jest.fn(() => false)
}
...
expect(Raven.isSetup).toHaveBeenCalled()
```

What am I missing? Do I need to use `jest.setMock('raven-js')` instead?

Comment: I maintain a Redux middleware for Raven: [raven-for-redux](https://github.com/captbaritone/raven-for-redux) Perhaps it could help. If it doesn't address your use case, I'd be curious to learn about the problem you are trying to solve. Maybe you could file an issue on the GitHub page.

Answer (score 2):

I maintain [raven-for-redux](https://github.com/captbaritone/raven-for-redux/) which is, perhaps unsurprisingly, a Raven middleware or Redux. It includes a Jest test suite, so I had to solve a similar problem. Rather than mock Raven, I opted to simply specify a custom transport using `Raven.setTransport()`. This allowed me avoid network calls in my tests but still test exactly what Raven was trying to do.

You can find the entire test here: https://github.com/captbaritone/raven-for-redux/blob/master/index.test.js

Answer (score 0):

You have to mock the imported module like this:

```
import Raven from 'raven-js' 
jest.mock('raven-js', ()=> ({
  isSetup: jest.fn(() => false)
}))

it('should call raven',()=> {
  //run you code
  expect(Raven.isSetup).toHaveBeenCalled()
})
```

Comment: So that works in the beforeEach block and if I console log out the value in the beforeEach block it has mocked it successfully but then when I run the test that calls the code Im testing it imports 'raven-js' and calls isSetup on the real Raven instance... Is it over writing the mock? Do I need to mock the import?

Comment: So you import it with `import raven from 'raven-js'` in you test?

Comment: In the code Im testing it does `import Raven from 'raven-js'`. I import that code into my test.

Comment: Ok, nevertheless tou import it into your module then `jest.setMock('raven-js'` is the way to go, will update my answer

Comment: Ahrg, sorry `jest.mock` of cause.

Answer (score 0):

It ended up having to be this, api change in Jest 20 maybe...

```
jest.mock('raven-js', () => {
    return { isSetup: jest.fn(() => false) }
})
```